# Getting the key value of localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to get the key for each item in local storage.

These are what I have stored so far:

```
'132', 'yes'
'15', 'yes'
'76', 'yes'
```

However, the following loop returns NULL:

```
 for(var i in localStorage){
     console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));

}
```

What would be the best way for me to get the `key` of one of the items listed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED:

```
for(var key in localStorage){
    console.log(key);
}
```

Or,

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    console.log(localStorage.key(i));
}
```

, that is if you'd like to track the index count in the loop.

Comment: Apologies, maybe I got the wording wrong. I'm trying to console.log the numbers, '132, '15', etc. The above code returns 'yes'.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the keys directly like so:

```
for (var key in localStorage) {
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log('Key:' + key);//Logs the key ex:132,15,76
        console.log('Value:' + localStorage[key]);//Logs the value ex:yes,yes
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, maybe I got the wording wrong. I'm trying to console.log the numbers, '132, '15', etc. The above code returns 'yes'.